# How to load crystal report to report viewer in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, report

I have tired by trying and trying but i am unable to do the job
my problem is i want to load my crystal report to report view. i have made my crystal report and i have one windows form with report viewer, but how to show report in my report viewer
 what I am trying is

```
private void frmRptViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            string SqlConnentionString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Connect.txt");


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnentionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeInfo.EmployeeCode, EmployeeInfo.DOJ,EmployeeInfo.GrossSalary,ea.Balance, EmployeeAdvance.MonthlyInst FROM  EmployeeInfo Left Outer JOIN EmployeeAdvance ON EmployeeInfo.EmployeeID = EmployeeAdvance.EmployeeID Left Outer Join (select employeeid,sum(dr)-sum(cr) as Balance from Deduction_Ledger where Deduction_type_ID = 1 Group By EmployeeiD ) ea on EmployeeInfo.employeeid = ea.employeeid where EmployeeInfo.dor is null", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter sdt = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            sdt.Fill(ds);
            EmpReport er = new EmpReport();
            er.SetDataSource(ds);
            reportViewer.ReportSource = er;
            reportViewer.Refresh();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
        }
    }


}
```

please please somebody help me
 thanks in advance

Comment: Issue is? An error being thrown, report viewer invisible etc?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not use C#

but i noticed that your SQL statement select from three tables EmployeeInfo, ea and EmployeeAdvance

in this case

you need to pass DATASET contain three tables to your report, not DATATABLE

see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372474/crystal-reports-datasource-in-visual-studio/23648885#23648885) , it may help you